# Running trials in python

Tags: python

I'm a beginner when it comes to using Python and wants to do simulations where I estimate pi using trials. I first important random numbers for both the x and y values (between 0 and 1), then I check to see if those numbers are inside the circle. If they are then I estimate pi using the formula:
(4 * (number of points inside circle/number of trials)).
My code is attached below. With the seed I'm using I should get a number around 3.02 but instead, am getting 4.00. Could anyone point in the direction of where I've gone wrong?

```
import random 

random.seed(1000)
```

`x_value = random.random()`

`y_value = random.random()`

```
print(x_value)
print(y_value)

pointsInCircle= 0 
numberOfTrials = 1000

for trials in range(trials):
    if 1 > ((x_value ** 2) + (y_value ** 2)):
        pointsInCircle = pointsInCircle + 1
    else:
        print("No estimation possbile")

pi = 4 * (pointsInCircle/numberOfTrials)

print(pi)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following 2 lines should go inside the for loop. At each trail it needs to have 2 random numbers which are different from the previous.

```
x_value = random.random()
y_value = random.random()
```

Hence the code should look like below.

```
import random 

random.seed(1000)

# print(x_value)
# print(y_value)

pointsInCircle= 0 
numberOfTrials = 1000

for trials in range(numberOfTrials):
    x_value = random.random()
    y_value = random.random()
    if 1 > ((x_value ** 2) + (y_value ** 2)):
        pointsInCircle = pointsInCircle + 1
    else:
        print("No estimation possbile")

pi = 4 * (pointsInCircle/numberOfTrials)

print(pi)
```

Which yields the answer `3.02`.

Comment: Yes just realized this on my end! Thanks very much for taking the time to help a beginner programmer - it is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I can provide a full solution without more information, but it seems like `pointsInCircle/numberOfTrials == 1`, therefore `pointsInCircle == numberOfTrials`.

Maybe use some print debugging to find the values of those two variables and see if that's the problem. If you get any more information, I'd be happy to help further!

Comment: Thanks very much for the quick response! I think I've made a big logic error. I should  develop my random numbers inside my loop so that for each trial, two random numbers are made.

Comment: Great! Glad I helped you.